# compiler is throwing me an error i cannot trace

Tags: function

error is: Function and definition differ

```
int GetItemBaseMaterialType(string sItem)//uses resrefs
{
string sMaterial = GetSubString(sItem, 9,3);
if(sMaterial == "ada") return 1;
if(sMaterial == "drk") return 3;
if(sMaterial == "mth" || sItem == "nx1_breastplate01" | "nw_maarcl037" | "nx1_chainmail01") return 5;
if(sMaterial == "rdh") return 9;
if(sMaterial == "slh") return 10
if(sMaterial == "uhh") return 11;
if(sMaterial == "wyh") return 12;

}
```

point of function is to return an int based on a string passed to the function; adding more strings so not in a hurry to resolve this

thanks in advance

Comment: What language am I looking at here?

Comment: This is literally the only Google result for that error. Are you sure you posted it right? Also, ya, what language is this?

Comment: hmm, sorry, forgot about this post... never did resolve this error; I decided it wasn't resolvable; language is specific to a game I play based on javascript; not entirely sure about actual language though as I gave up programming eons ago; last thing I programmed for was the C64 in assembly...